# Q - Toggle a user's Global Setting (WiFi, Location, etc) - 2 ideas.. Thoughts?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

**My Question:**
How can I turn OFF one of a user's Global Settings, (such as "Location" or "Bluetooth", or "WiFi", etc)..?

After learning I can NOT do this via Permissions, I came up with a couple of other ideas/thoughts on *possibly* how to do it, and need some clarification!

**( 1 ) -** Would obtaining "Phone Administrator" privileges, (similar to the way Launchers like NOVA do to perform certain actions) work?
**NOTE:** I'm referring to the App's you might find in (Settings > Lock screen and security > Other security settings > Phone administrators).

*OR..*

**( 2 ) -** Would becoming a "Device Owner" (like in the "Device Owner" Android Code Sample in Android Studio) be of any help?

:/

I'm at a total loss for ideas at this point, and don't want my work thus far to go to waste..
Note that I am actually trying to turn OFF a setting, NOT on.. But I doubt that makes any difference..

If anybody could please provide me with some answers to the above questions, I would greatly appreciate it!
Any information whatsoever would greatly help me!
**Thanks!** :)

Comment: For WIFI as example, have you tried turning it off with WifiManager?

Comment: @Carlton , Thank you for the info on the WiFi part of it, very much appreciated.. Unfortunately, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how I can go about turning the "Location" setting OFF now.. Any ideas? or thoughts about the ideas I had, such as using one of the solutions I posted? Would either of those work for gaining the privileges needed?

Comment: Check out my answer below, I added for Wifi, Bluetooth and Location, I hope it will help you with your issues. Please, if it's of any help, thumbs up and "accept" my answer. If there's anything else, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

**For Wifi, try this:**

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);        //TURN WIFI ON
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);       //TURN WIFI OFF
```

Also, add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**For Bluetooth, try this:**

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
bluetooth.disable();
bluetooth.enable();
```

And add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

**For Location, try this:** (NOTE: It is not allowed/"possible" to turn GPS/Location on/off on Android 4.0 and above, however, some reported that this workaround may work)

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);


    }
}
// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you with your problem, If the problem still persist, or if you wish to know how to turn on/off other global settings, search this forum and I'm sure you'll find something helpful.